# Query whether MacBook is plugged or on battery from shell script

Tags: command-line, battery, script, power

I am writing a shell script that I will leave running in background for some syncing tasks. I would like this script to behave differently depending on whether my MacBook is plugged to a power source, or on battery.

Is there a way to determine from within a shell script, wether my MacBook (which is running the script) is on battery, or plugged?

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the `pmset` (power management settings) tool from a shell script to ascertain if you are running on battery or AC power. See the manual pages (`man pmset`) for more details.

For example, when connected to AC power:

```
pmset -g ps

Now drawing from 'AC Power'
 -InternalBattery-0 (id=5898339)        79%; charging; (no estimate)     present: true
```

And when running on battery power:

```
pmset -g ps

Now drawing from 'Battery Power'
 -InternalBattery-0 (id=5898339)        79%; discharging; (no estimate) present: true
```

To capture the current power condition in a bash script, use something like:

```
[[ $(pmset -g ps|grep "AC Power") ]] && state="AC" || state="BATT"
```

An alternative way to capture the current power source was suggested by @nohillside. This directly snips the token "AC" or "Battery" from `pmset` output:

```
state=$(pmset -g ps|sed -nE "s|.*'(.*) Power.*|\1|p")
```